# What technical challenges prevent non-centralized messaging apps from servicing billions of users?

Tags: privacy, instant-messaging

The most popular messaging apps to date (e.g. telegram), even those that are "privacy by design" (e.g. signal, threema), are centralized.

What technical challenges prevent peer-to-peer (e.g. jami) or decentralized (e.g. blockchain) messaging apps from servicing billions of users?

Comment: Public look for features not architecture, so there is marketing challenges, those decentralized messaging apps are not able to break through markets as millions of apps out there. Technical challenges are yet to be identified.

Comment: This is not a security question but a performance question. And there is one big challenge to overcome: how do you find your friends/family on a p2p or decentralised network? If you have to manually connect with each person you want to contact, then that slows down the adoption rate and makes it far less commercially viable.